# What happens if you ask the Commune spell a paradox?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

What happens if a PC asks the Commune spell a paradox?

> Would the answer to my question be no?

Actually, if the answer is no, then it is no, so the real answer would be yes, but again, yes is not the expected outcome and so the answer would be no again.. and so on.

**This is similar to the Orc paradox: (added to answer a comment)**

> A Orc caught a dwarf and said to him: "tell me anything, I'll know if you lie because I can sense it. If you say the truth you will be beheaded, if you say a lie I'll rip you apart." The dwarf think on that for a while, and finally say "I'll be ripped apart". If the Orc rip him then the dwarf was right and should have been beheaded. If the Orc behead him the dward was wrong and then it should have been ripped apart

Comment: Not that it matters to the heart of the question, but your example question isn't actually a paradox. Beyond using "my" instead of "this", limiting the response to considering the question itself, one could easily answer it with yes/no, the answer *would* be no, *if* you asked it, but you didn't.

Comment: You mention "the Orc paradox" as if it's an obviously analogous example, but I've never heard of it - got a link or something?

Comment: I’m wondering why the pc would want to ask a question where there is no value to the answer.  Example: is the set of all non-self-contained sets self-contained?  If it isn’t, then it is and if it is, then it isn’t.  No value

Comment: Well, since a deity answer the question, maybe for a particular quest asking that question creates a infinite loop in the deity and no one else in the game will ever be able to use commune (not with that deity at least). Maybe some cult may deceive another PC to say that so they can still use commune, while that PC that was affine to that deity will no ever be able to use Commune again to uncover secrets of the cult. :)

Comment: @Miniman Sure: A Orc caught a dwarf and said to him: "tell me anything, I'll know if you lie because I can sense it. If you say the truth you will be beheaded, if you say a lie I'll rip you apart." The dwarf think on that for a while, and finally say "I'll be be ripped apart". If the Orc rip him then the dwarf was right and should have been beheaded. If the Orc behead him the dward was wrong and then it should have been ripped apart.

Answer (score 13):

## Up to the GM, but probably "Unclear", or some other non-answer

*Commune* specifically includes the possibility of more-than-one-word answers:

> In a case where a one-word answer could be misleading or contrary to the deity's interests, the DM might offer a short phrase as an answer instead.

So the deity of choice will respond with "Unclear" or "Don't waste my time with silly questions", or some other appropriate response.

Answer (score 9):

Keep reading the spell description.

> Divine beings aren't necessarily omniscient, so you might receive "unclear" as an answer if a question pertains to information that lies beyond the deity's knowledge. In a case where a one-word answer could be misleading or contrary to the deity's interests, the GM might offer a short phrase as an answer instead.

[source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/commune)

This is not a forced binary. You are asking a divine being a question that will *normally* be answered with Yes or No. Attempting to 'break' the spell by asking a Paradox may result in the generic 'Unclear' answer...or, if your DM so chooses, you may get a phrased response like "That is a paradox" or "Don't waste my time" or whatever else your DM chooses to have the being respond with.

Comment: The Magic 8-Ball (or an online simulator) is a useful tool for a DM in these circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

This is pretty well answered in the spell's description.

> Divine beings aren't necessarily omniscient, so **you might receive "unclear" as an answer** if a question pertains to information that lies beyond the deity's knowledge. In a case where a one-word answer could be misleading or contrary to the deity's interests, **the DM might offer a short phrase as an answer instead.**

The answer doesn't **have** to be straight yes or no if there's no clear "yes/no" answer. In the case of a paradox then "unclear" or a short phrase may be used instead.